# Añadir clase html desde otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Tengo un archivo llamado header.php con el header y navegación, al que llamo desde todas las paginas que lo requieran, y necesito insertarle la clase "active" a cada enlace de la navegación, para que desde cada pagina se aplique un estilo (ejemplo, si estoy en inicio.php, el boton de inicio cambia de estilo). El problema es que no se como hacer para que desde la pagina inicio se añada la clase "active" en header.php. Ayuda a resolver ese problema o alguna alternativa...

El código es:

**HTML header.php**

```
<header>
    <img src="img/logo1.png" alt="LogotipoPrincipal" class="logop margenes-g">
    <nav class="principal">
        <ul class="margenes-g">
            <a href="#" class="rmenu">Menu</a>
            <div class="menucontent">
                <a id="hp1" class="" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
                <a id="hp2" href="#">Productos</a>
                <a id="hp3" href="#">Capacitación</a>
                <a id="hp4" href="#">Servicios</a>
                <a id="hp5" href="#">Descargas</a>
                <a id="hp6" href="#">Soporte</a>
                <a id="hp7" href="#">Nosotros</a>
                <a id="hp8" href="contacto.php">Contacto</a>
                <a id="hp9" href="pruebas.php">Pruebas</a>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**HTML inicio.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>ASPEL - pruebas</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
include("parts/header.php")
?>


<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload = function(){
    <iframe id="iframeHeader" src="parts/header.php"></iframe> 

    var iframeDocument = 
    document.getElementById('iframeHeader').contentDocument;
    var hp9 = iframeDocument.getElementById('hp9');
    hp9.classList.add('active');

    **//intento faillido**

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.active{
/*border-top: solid var(--azul1) 3px !important;*/
background-color:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Si usas javaScript puro puedes usar esto en cada pagina que visita el usuario

```
 document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      // document ready

     document.getElementById("action").classList.toggle('active');

    }
```

action es el id del enlace que quieres que tenga la clase. El metodo toggle si el enlace tiene la clase la quta, si el enlace no tiene la clase se la pone.

Edit2: 
He usado jQuery

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    // document ready

        // elementos de la lista
      var nav= $("a"); 

      // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
      nav.click(function() {
         // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
         nav.removeClass("active");
         // activamos el elemento clicado.
         $(this).addClass("active");
      });


  }
};
```

Quedaria asi.

Comment: Porque necesito aplicar el diseño a un solo botón a la vez, según la pagina, no a todos. Esto varia segun la página

Comment: Si ya entendí, no había entendido el problema.

Comment: Checa a ver si te sirve

Comment: Sabrias como hacer para que eso se aplique en otra página (header.php)?

Comment: Se me ocurre eso que edite, no se que tantos archivos manejes, recuerda que mientras sea funcional no lo toques jajaja.